# React setState with multiple AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I want the view to always be updated with the result of the latest call to `searchWiki()`. I've used a module that resolves repeated calls to `$.ajax` to the value returned by the most recent call.

It still seems to go out of sync and show the result of previous calls however. I'm guessing this is because `setState` is async? How should I keep the two async operations in sync?

In addition, I realize I should put in a debounce somewhere, but I'm not sure what I should debounce. `handleChange`, `searchWiki` or `latestAjax`?

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/prashcr/pen/obXvWv
Try typing stuff then backspacing to see what I mean.

Search component

```
<div style={style}>
  <input 
    value={this.props.search}
    // this calls searchWiki with e.target.value
    onInput={this.handleChange}
  />
</div>
```

searchWiki function of parent component

```
searchWiki (search) {
  console.log('searchWiki called with: ' + search);
  if (!search) {
    this.setState({results: []});
  }
  else {
    // "latest" taken from https://github.com/bjoerge/promise-latest
    let latestAjax = latest($.ajax);
    let options = {
      url: this.props.url + search,
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    };
    latestAjax(options)
    .then(data => {
      var results = data.query.search.map(res => {
        res.url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + encodeURIComponent(res.title);
        return res;
      });
      this.setState({results: results});
    })
    .error(e => console.log(e.message));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handleChange` function is too generic to be debounced with a hardcoded value as you might want to use this search component elsewhere. However, you still want to catch the repeating action as early as possible and ensure that it never does any unnecessary work.

Therefore I would suggest that you debounce the `handleChange` function with an optional prop, defaulting to 0ms.

```
getDefaultProps() {
  return {
    debounce: 0
  };
},
render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <input
        // ...
        onInput={debounce(this.handleChange, this.props.debounce)}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then make sure you pass this prop whenever you want to debounce the handler.

```
<Search onSearch={this.searchWiki} debounce={1000} />
```

Your other problem is happening because you are calling `latest` inside your `searchWiki` function and you only call the returned function once! Each time you call `searchWiki` you create a new `latestAjax` function.

For it to work, you'll need to call the returned function multiple times.

This means defining the wrapped `$.ajax` function outside of `searchWiki` function.

```
latestAjax: latest($.ajax),
searchWiki(search) {
  // ...
  this.latestAjax(options)
    .then(data => {

    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, thanks! Would you happen to have any suggestions regarding my other problem? i.e. keeping the state of my other view updated with the results from the current state of `Search`

Comment: Ah, silly me. The AJAX part of it works fluently now! One last thing, what's a good way to set `this.state.results` to `[]` when `search` is empty? Trying to do it as shown in my code leads to the last AJAX call returning after the results have been cleared.

Comment: Set a flag so that when the promise resolves it knows that it should ignore the results. The other option would be to clear with a timeout, but that's kinda messy.

Comment: The flag couldn't live in state or props, it would have to be global, which I wanted to avoid. Instead, I made `latestAjax` an anonymous function that either calls `$.ajax` and returns its Promise or returns Promise.resolve(null), if search was empty.